# Receiving error message when trying to install Pycurl

Tags: python, command-prompt

I am trying to install Pycurl 7.19.3.1 and am receiving the following error message in Command Prompt:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Oleg Salenko>cd C:\Python33\scripts

C:\Python33\Scripts>pip3.3 install pycurl==7.19.3.1
Downloading/unpacking pycurl==7.19.3.1
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\olegsa~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Oleg Sal
enko\pycurl\setup.py) egg_info for package pycurl
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 10 in c:\users\chris\app
data\local\temp\pip_build_chris\pycurl
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\chris\pip\pip.log
```

Does anyone know what the issue is here at all?

The log printed to the above path is saying the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Python33\Scripts\pip3.3 run on 04/02/14 21:29:32
Downloading/unpacking pycurl==7.19.3.1
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/
  URLs to search for versions for pycurl==7.19.3.1:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/7.19.3.1
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/7.19.3.1
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/7.19.3.1: 404 Client Error: Not Found
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/7.19.3.1 when looking for download links for pycurl==7.19.3.1
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.0.2.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=125dc00488a543788ebdedec8465534b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.0.3.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=a1dbbdf183c525e85de7038bd1f2f04f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.1.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=6a7423ee6916ecffc00d26d667b14207 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=86dc7d4484c0b41da7568644164e1b32 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.0.2.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=374fd1dd1d5934522b73f4c994856be4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.0.3.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=55559246b2bc3f518b2ce82cb9934463 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.1.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=a04be4550de35ecde11e3e70dc53b138 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=4bbb209836e32dd2bf730efb20850f1a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.1.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=1edcec141fea88ac4aa34207608d0aa2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=95979e8267caadeab6357b0bf2abc39b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.1.win32-py3.3.exe#md5=4a6510a45d452eafbd432a6c97f86e70 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.win32-py3.3.exe#md5=411b3f5199f971fcb16ca263397033b7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.18.2.tar.gz#md5=819a591aabcade5122bbd476165cb72f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version: 7.18.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.0.1.tar.gz#md5=bf737819edcd5b3d9d93b9fc4cd8e003 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version: 7.19.0.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.0.2.tar.gz#md5=518be33976dbc6838e42495ada64b43f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version: 7.19.0.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.0.3.tar.gz#md5=3c3e6033185a49438820af215a936120 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version: 7.19.0.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz#md5=074cd44079bb68697f5d8751102b384b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version: 7.19.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.1.tar.gz#md5=6df8fa7fe8b680d93248da1f8d4fcd12 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version: 7.19.3.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.tar.gz#md5=b9091b7438d3de1552e28862d2971cd1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version: 7.19.3
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.18.2.tar.gz#md5=819a591aabcade5122bbd476165cb72f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version 7.18.2 doesn't match ==7.19.3.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.0.1.tar.gz#md5=bf737819edcd5b3d9d93b9fc4cd8e003 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version 7.19.0.1 doesn't match ==7.19.3.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.0.2.tar.gz#md5=518be33976dbc6838e42495ada64b43f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version 7.19.0.2 doesn't match ==7.19.3.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.0.3.tar.gz#md5=3c3e6033185a49438820af215a936120 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version 7.19.0.3 doesn't match ==7.19.3.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz#md5=074cd44079bb68697f5d8751102b384b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version 7.19.0 doesn't match ==7.19.3.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.tar.gz#md5=b9091b7438d3de1552e28862d2971cd1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/), version 7.19.3 doesn't match ==7.19.3.1
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.1.tar.gz#md5=6df8fa7fe8b680d93248da1f8d4fcd12 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/)
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\chris\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_chris\pycurl\setup.py) egg_info for package pycurl
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir c:\users\chris\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_chris...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 10 in c:\users\chris\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_chris\pycurl
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 325, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 10 in c:\users\chris\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_chris\pycurl
```

Does this mean that Pycurl 7.19.3.1 no longer exists as a download link?

Thanks

Comment: EDITED POST - ERROR MESSAGE AMENDED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to install and don't want to compile it, then download binary version of it from  [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl) ([pycurl‑7.19.3.1.win32‑py3.3.exe](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/sn5ub7d9/pycurl-7.19.3.1.win32-py3.3.exe))

Comment: i dont follow you. why would i want to not compile it?

Comment: @user3045351, Because it is more complex in `Windows`, you need to have same compiler that your python is complied with that, and some other libraries and sources, but why you don't want to use binary version that is ready?

Comment: im relatively new to python. im not sure what the difference between a binary and compiled version of a library is.

Comment: im running python 3.3.0...is this not the same as python3.3? the binary version would not install because it said it could not find a version of 3.3

Comment: Try other version of 3.3 from [here](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/), for example  [pycurl-7.19.3.win32-py3.3.msi](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/pycurl-7.19.3.win32-py3.3.msi)

Comment: If you get error again, then download zip version of it: [pycurl-7.19.3.1.win32-py3.3.zip](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/pycurl-7.19.3.1.win32-py3.3.zip), then extract it and then copy all content of it that is `Lib` and `doc` folders to  your `C:/Python33/` folder.